# All Programs folder not showing Ion on Inno Setup created exe file

Tags: vb.net, inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup and have used it with no issues for years.

I am NOT seeing the an icon on the app in "All Programs".

The desktop shortcut has the icon showing and the Programs and Features listing has the icon.

The Beakout and CardPrinter were installed with Inno Setup.

I have tried various changes to the Inno Setup file with no positive result.

The question Is can anyone see what might be wrong with the Inno Setup syntax?

The uninstall.exe file displays the icon correctly.

[image: All Programs]

```
AppName=CheckBook
AppVersion=1.5
AppPublisher=Pharmacy Solutions
DefaultDirName=C:\Users\Dwight\Documents\A A A A VS Apps\CheckBook
DisableDirPage=yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputDir="C:\Users\Dwight\Documents\A A A A VS Apps"
OutputBaseFilename=SetupCheckBook
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\Dwight\source\repos\CheckBook\CheckBook\cb.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

UninstallDisplayIcon=C:\Users\Dwight\source\repos\CheckBook\CheckBook\cb.ico

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\Dwight\source\repos\CheckBook\CheckBook\bin\Debug\CheckBook.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Dwight\source\repos\CheckBook\CheckBook\cb.ico";DestDir:"{app}";Flags:ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Dwight\source\repos\CheckBook\CheckBook\bin\Debug\System.Data.SQLite.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Dwight\source\repos\CheckBook\CheckBook\bin\Debug\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Dwight\source\repos\CheckBook\CheckBook\bin\Debug\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\CheckBook"; Filename: "{app}\CheckBook.exe" 
Name: "{commondesktop}\CheckBook"; Filename: "{app}\CheckBook.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon ; IconFilename: "{app}\cb.ico"


[Run]
Filename: "{app}\CheckBook.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,CheckBook}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

I changed the [Icons] code to this format and now the only item that is not displaying the cb.ico is the CheckBook.exe file

```html
[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\CheckBook"; Filename: "{app}\CheckBook.exe";Tasks: desktopicon ; IconFilename: "{app}\cb.ico"  
Name: "{commondesktop}\CheckBook"; Filename: "{app}\CheckBook.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon ; IconFilename: "{app}\cb.ico"
```

This Question was closed with the statement that the link provided answered the question. That is not the case the link was explored and failed to produce the desired results. I am trying to attach an icon to CheckBoo.exe.
So Closing the question and making reference to the older post does not provide the desired answer FWIW

Comment: No one here told you to use <br>. The site editor doesn't allow many things with HTML, and unless you're posting HTML code you don't need it at all. And I'm not offended - I was offering information to make things better for you in the future by letting you know it wasn't supported. The Enter key works here just like it would in any text editor, and you should use it to add paragraph breaks.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I tried the format you provided in the link with no luck I did make some headway SEE the updated Inno Setup [Icons] file syntax The only file not displaying the icon now is the CheckBook.exe NOTE I also create SetupCheckBook.exe Thanks

Comment: So edit your question to show the new *"format"*.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I did edit the question with the additional changes. And this produces the desired results with the exception that the CheckBook.exe does not display the cb.ico

Comment: Your edit added `[Icons]` section. The question I've linked (and the answer here by @mirtheil) explains  that the problem is the `UninstallDisplayIcon` directive. So no, I do not see you *"tried the format I provided"*.

Comment: I've read your question twice now. It's really hard to understand. So is this about Windows 7 *"Start > All Programs"*?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl As the Inno Setup code is now the only place the icon is not showing is the CheckBook.exe/ All the other files associated with the app display the icon SetupCheckBook.exe and uninstall as well as when you click START and select All Programs. The Inno Setup is the same format I have used on other older projects

Answer (score 1):

The `UninstallDisplayIcon` directive needs a file local to the installed system, not the source system.
If you change it to:

```
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\cb.ico
```

It should work correctly.
The documentation shows examples using the `{app}` constant.  From the Docs:

> Description:
>
> This lets you specify a particular icon file (either an executable or an .ico file) to display for the Uninstall entry in the Add/Remove Programs Control Panel applet. The filename will normally begin with a directory constant.
>
> If the file you specify contains multiple icons, you may append the suffix ",n" to specify an icon index, where n is the zero-based numeric index.
>
> If this directive is not specified or is blank, Windows will select an icon itself, which may not be the one you prefer.

```
Examples:
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe,1
```

Comment: Just tried your solution and I have tried the other two examples I am still seeing no icon in All Programs ALL the other places have the correct icon ONLY issue I might be guessing is I have no icons in the title bar or any of the forms I used the Wizard to Create the Inno Setup file I usually just copy and paste a file that works and generate a new ApId the icon size is 256x256 ? ?

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are saying. I would recommend reviewing basic grammar to avoid run-on sentences, comma splices, etc.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Suggestion appreciated I have edited the post with a fix for the issue of the All Programs NOT displaying the icon The only issue now is the CheckBook.exe created file does not display the cb.ico all the other created files display the cb.ico icon All Programs is seen when you click START then select All Programs

Comment: I would refer the honorable poster to my previous comment. (Hint: You are still writing run-on sentences that make what you are saying hard to understand.)